# How can I change bootstrap form direction, text right textbox left?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[example of it at this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b52Gc.png)

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">עיר</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="Text5" type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">רחוב</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control" id="Text6" type="text" />
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">מס'</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to change direction to be: right to left.
text- right, textbox- left

Comment: Have you tried `direction: rtl`?

Comment: yes i wrote in my CSS file:
body{direction:rtl}
and didin't worked

Answer (score 5):

You can use `direction: rtl;` on your forms child elements

```css
.form-horizontal * {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">עיר</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="Text5" type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">רחוב</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control" id="Text6" type="text" />
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">מס'</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

just create a file call it bootstrap-ext-rtl.css || bootstrap-ext-rtl.module.css
that contains:

```
.rtl { direction: rtl}
.ltr { direction: ltr}
.bidi-rtl{ direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override }
/* with/without text-align or whatever you want :P */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [text-right](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) class.

Comment: This is incorrect.
This won't affect the direction of the text rather the text alignment.